# JS - assigning function to variable

Tags: javascript

As we all know, this following **will not run the a() function** so the **alert box will not appear**

```js
// 1st
function a() {
  alert('A!');
  return function() {
    alert('B!');
  };
};
```

and we know that the following code **will run the a() function** and **alert box 'A!' will appear**

```js
// 2nd
function a() {
  alert('A!');
  return function() {
    alert('B!');
  };
};
a(); // calling function
```

**However**, if we run following code, the **a() function will be called** and **alert box 'A!' will also appear**, just like the second code above

```js
// 3rd
function a() {
  alert('A!');
  return function() {
    alert('B!');
  };
};
var x = a(); // assigning function to new variable
```

**QUESTION:**
why does this happen (on 3rd snippet)? we didn't call the a() function yet (my current understanding). Didn't we just assigning x to a() function?.

Comment: `()` this will call the function. And will assign the return value of that function to `x`

Comment: Anything with parenthesis `()` will find the function/method of that name and will invoke it... No matter where you write!

Comment: *we didn't call the a() function* - yes you did

Comment: The name of the function is `a`, not `a()`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Didn't we just assigning x to a() function?.

No, you assigned the returned value from a() to x.

If you don't want to call `a`, then do

```
var x = a;
```

and later do

```
x();
```

Answer (score 6):

You're wrong. You are invoking the function:

```
var x = a(); // assigning function to new variable
```

This line of code says invoke `a` when you write `a()`. The parentheses indicate an invocation.

To assign a function to a variable you have to use just the name, such as:

```
var x = a;
```

or pass the name to a function `f`:

```
f(a)
```

As a counter-example you invoke it in this next line of code and pass to `g` not the function be the result of its execution:

```
g(a())
```